# extundelete used after mv command

Tags: data-recovery, partitioning, mv

I needed to move a directory temp/ between sda1 -> sda2 partition to free some space in sda1.

Some how I ended up:

sda1: the directory temp/ is not shown
sda2: no directory moved here.

I used testdisk and I could recover most of the file and I can see that the directory temp/ and all sub directories are still on sda1 and I hoped to use extundelete to make temp/ visible but did not work.

I think I have most of the data recovered but the problem is that the sda1 is still full (did not free any extra space apparently)

I used extundelete from a live installation on sda1 not mounted in this way:
extundelete /dev/sda1 --restore-directory /mnt/temp

the program shows 556 inodes to restore and ends with 556 inodes not restored (if it helps). After normal reboot still no sign of the temp/ directory

Any hint?
How do I recovery the faulty mv command?
How do I release the memory?

I runs lubuntu 16.04

thanks

Comment: What exact command did you use? You can't `mv` files between partitions ... only between folders. I guess `/mnt/temp` is the mount point of sda1 ... Where is sda2 mounted?

Comment: It is
/    /dev/sda1 with /mnt/temp ( temporary files before moving these to other directories).It contains some subdirectories. I know it is not 'correct' but easier to move things around
/mnt/doc /dev/sda2

i did not know about not using mv between different partitions :( thanks for the info:)

 in any case I tried to move the folder temp aiming to something like

/mnt/doc/temp 

so temp is a directory in /dev/sda2

i hope this help

Comment: Ok how I understand /dev/sda1 is mounted to `/` and it has a path `/mnt/temp` on it. /dev/sda1 is mounted to `/mnt/doc`. Than you could do something like 1. Make new directory in `sudo mkdir /mnt/doc/temp` 2. COPY not move the files with `sudo cp /mnt/temp/* /mnt/doc/temp` 3. Check if all files reached. 4. If everything went good than remove the old files via `sudo rm -rf /mnt/temp`. This way you confirm before removing the files

Comment: Just to be sure: can you write/copy any file to /dev/sda2 in /mnt/doc ?

Comment: quick amend on your last commend. /dev/sda2 is mounted on /mnt/doc.

Comment: /dev/sda2 is mounted on /mnt/doc but otherwise correct.Now I'm aware of the right process.Unfortunately I've already done mv -t /mnt/doc/temp /mnt/temp (I think i used mv this way with no errors and effective until I reboot the OS). If I now use ls -la under /mnt the temp directory is not shown but testdisk on /dev/sda1 shows it in red and all subfolders and file in white (I guess read means deleted or at least not visible). So the directory is there (taking also space) but it is not accessible. I'm guessing how I can revert the process being able to see, move and delete safely it

Comment: Oh now I get it you used it the other way round so ... you copied all contents from /mnt/doc/temp (which was empty) to /mnt/temp overwriting it. Did you run extundelete within the system or did you run it booting a live system?

Comment: mv -t /mnt/doc/temp /mnt/temp works reverse. from man mv -> mv [OPTION]... -t DIRECTORY SOURCE...I did not copy empty directory. I tried to copy the actual one on sda1 to destination which was empty. I tried extundelete from Live Ubuntu Usb with /dev/sda1 not mounted but no success. I tried twice and rebooted. Directory still hidden there under /mnt/temp :(

Comment: Hm sorry for that .. that's a stupid situation. I suggest you close this question and open a new one but including all the information you gave me here in the comments so people see at once what this is about. Try to format all your paths and code snippets. A better formatted and structured question will draw more attention. Also choose a title that fits with your question rather than what you did like `Help me restore my data`. Try to list exactly what you did and tried so far. Sorry I couldn't help you but I think this needs attention of further advanced Ubuntu users